# jQueryValidaton in Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I am trying to validate a field by using jQueryValidation plugin. I am getting 'unexpected string error' on the field that I am trying to validate. I believe there is a syntax error in referencing Amount field. I am not able to resolve this. I also tried to have required within double quotes but it didn't work. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: try `j$('input[id*=amount]')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `!$Component` Global variable to reference the name of elements to apply proper rule. You have to provide static names during declaration, dynamic declaration like `j$('[id$=amount]').attr('name')` will not work here. See the example below.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:form id="myform">
        <apex:pageBlock title="Account Edit" mode="Edit" id="theBlock">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons id="theButtons">
                <apex:commandButton value="Save"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Information" id="theSection">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}" id="Unit"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
        j$(document).ready(function () {
            j$('[id$=myform]').validate({
                rules: {
                    "{!$Component.myform.theBlock.theSection.Unit}": {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    "{!$Component.myform.theBlock.theSection.Unit}": {
                        required: "Please, enter a name"
                    }
                },
                submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
                    alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
                    return false; // for demo
                }
            });            
        });    
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It helped. I was able to get around the syntax error but in the browser it loads null. Appericate your help. Here is my code "{!$Component.myForm.myPageBlock.infoSection.estFeeSection.amount}":
Browser load:
http://screencast.com/t/cDc4Q9AipIKF
DOM:
http://screencast.com/t/o6S2rv8zG

Comment: It seems you have not given id attribute for a nested apex element between infoSection and estFeeSection. you have to provide id attribute for all nested apex element. Plese see this link for details.

Comment: I couldn't see the link available from your comments!

Comment: Here is the link, so every element has a id https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_component.htm

Comment: Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The selector should be element name, not an Object. Replace `j$("[id$=amount]")` with element name like `amount`.

> rules (default: rules are read from markup (classes, attributes, data))
>   Type: Object
>   Key/value pairs defining custom rules. Key is the name of an element (or a group of checkboxes/radio buttons), value is an object consisting of rule/parameter pairs or a plain String. Can be combined with class/attribute/data rules. Each rule can be specified as having a depends-property to apply the rule only in certain conditions.

Comment: Visualforce doesn't accept that way. I followed the article mentioned here to have it as j$('[id$=amount]'). https://th3silverlining.com/2010/03/02/visualforce-form-validation-enhanced/#comment-15565